# Assigning column names from a list to a table

Tags: python, pandas

I have, say, a 100 row by 25 column data table with no column headers. I have a 25-item list that I would like to assign as the column headers to the data table (they're in the right order already). I don't know how to do this efficiently using pandas. Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just assign to the `columns` attribute directly.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> # create three rows of [0, 1, 2]
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame([range(3), range(3), range(3)])
>>> print df
   0  1  2
0  0  1  2
1  0  1  2
2  0  1  2
>>> my_columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> df.columns = my_columns
>>> print df
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  0  1  2
2  0  1  2
```

You can also assign to index to accomplish something similar

```
>>> df.index = ["row1", "row2", "row3"]
>>> print df
      a  b  c
row1  0  1  2
row2  0  1  2
row3  0  1  2
```

Comment: Commenting on the first code-formatted section: for the my_columns can I just replace that with my list.txt file rather than type out the individual column names?

Comment: how do you load your list.txt?

Comment: you can pass it any list. I just created a dummy list for the purposes of the example. e.g., if you use the `csv` module to produce a list, it will work here.

Answer (score 4):

There is a names argument for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

> `names` : array-like
>          List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you
>         should explicitly pass `header=None`

That is, you want to be doing something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fie_name, header=None, names=col_headers_list)
```

Comment: Maybe I've been up for too long and I need sleep but this isn't that clear to me. Can you clarify it a little more please?

Comment: If you already have the DataFrame use @Jeff's answer, if not then you can create the column names whilst reading from csv directly to a DataFrame.