# How to skip text being used as column heading using python

Tags: python, pandas, text, import, columnheader

I am importing a web log text file in Python using Pandas. Python is reading the headers however has used the text "Fields:" as a header and has then added another column of blanks (NaN's) at the end. How can I stop this text being used as a column heading?

here is my code:

```
arr = pd.read_table("path", skiprows=3, delim_whitespace=True,      na_values=True)
```

Here is the start of the file:

Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5

Version: 1.0

Date: 2014-08-01 00:00:25

Fields: date time

2014-08-01 00:00:25...

Result is that 'Fields' is being used as a column heading and a column full of NaN values is being created for column 'time'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it calling `read_table` twice.

```
# reads the forth line into 1x1 df being a string, 
# then splits it and skips the first field:
col_names = pd.read_table('path', skiprows=3, nrows=1, header=None).iloc[0,0].split()[1:]
# reads the actual data:
df = pd.read_table('path', sep=' ', skiprows=4, names=col_names)
```

If you already know the names of the columns (eg. `date` and `time`) then it's even simpler:

```
df = pd.read_table('path', sep=' ', skiprows=4, names = ['date', 'time'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want `skiprows = 4` and `header = None`

Comment: Thanks, I did that as a workaround and added the column headings back in using this qanda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018638/assigning-column-names-from-a-list-to-a-table    But surely there's a better way rather than having it  read the wrong text

Comment: Oh yea, i didn't understand your question. you should just edit the file and replace `'Fields: '` with `''` (you could do this in your python script with `replace`)